# scalapb-maven-example from https://github.com/aegnor/scalapb-maven-example gives me error

Tags: maven, scalapb

I am trying the run the example from https://github.com/aegnor/scalapb-maven-example and I am getting the following error.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java (generate-scala-protobuf-classes) on project scalapb-maven: 
>   Execution generate-scala-protobuf-classes of goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:java failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find com.trueaccord.scalapb:scalapbc:jar:0.4.20 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Comment: Can you delete your `C:/Users/your_user_name/.m2/repository` folder and try running the application again. Use `mvn clean install -U` to run the application.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the example here https://github.com/thesamet/scalapb-maven-example

Also, you probably want to change 0.4.20 to the latest 0.5.x version (currently 0.5.44)

Comment: I followed the instructions, also did a mvn clean, cleaned repo folders... Getting the following error

Comment: [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'scala' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/var/root/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]

Comment: I have scala 2.11

Comment: This is my POM file. Please help

Comment: I just posted an issue on github  because I could not fit in my pom file here.

https://github.com/thesamet/scalapb-maven-example/issues/1